# Why does adding a spacer truncate text even though there's room in the view?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to add a spacer to fill the space between two different views of various stacks of text. When I add the spacer, the text gets truncated with "..." even though there is available room in the view for all the text.

I've tried removing the lineLimit of 1 and a variety of minLength's for the Spacer with no success

```swift
HStack{
                //Active player information
                if self.player.isHomeTeam {
                    ActiveOrNotIndicator(player: self.player)
                    PlayerSummary(player: self.player)
                    Spacer()
                    FantasyPointTotal(player: self.player)
                } else {
                    FantasyPointTotal(player: self.player)
                    Spacer()
                    PlayerSummary(player: self.player)
                    ActiveOrNotIndicator(player: self.player)
                }
        }
```

This truncates the PlayerSummary view's text like [image: so]

Here it is without the [image: spacer]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in iOS 13.0. I have the same problem on iOS 13.0 devices. However, running the same code on iOS 13.1 (beta 4) works as expected.